# Cores assigned to SLURM job

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, slurm

Let's say I want to submit a slurm job just assigning the total amount of tasks (--ntasks=someNumber), without specifying the number of nodes and the tasks per node. Is there a way to know within the launched slurm script how many cores are assigned by slurm for each of the reserved nodes? I need to know this info to properly create a machinefile for the program I'm launching, that must be structured like this:

> ```
> node02:7
> node06:14
> node09:3
> ```

Once the job is launched, the only way I figured out to see what cores have been allocated on the nodes is using the command:

> scontrol show jobid -dd

In its output the abovementioned info is stored (together with plenty of other details).
Is there a better way to get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `srun` documentation illustrates creating a machine file is by running `srun hostname`. To get the output you want you could run

```
srun hostname -s | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2":"$1}' > $MACHINEFILE
```

You should check the documentation of your program to see if it accepts a machine file with repetitions rather than a suffix count. If so you can simplify the command as

```
srun hostname -s > $MACHINEFILE
```

And of course the first step is actually to make sure you indeed need a machine file in the first place as many parallel programs/libraries have Slurm support and can gather the needed information from the environment variables setup by Slurm upon job start.